# How to return date values from an arrayformula in an index:match formula (left/right function)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use an index-match function from a text string that was converted from an Array. This is the spreadsheet I'm working on, in row M I'm trying to return a date value from a linked spreadsheet (metabase data), that has the dates that the linked "assignments" started on.

[image: 0]

The metabase data spreadsheet is as follows:

[image]

As you can see in the first image, I've been using left and right function to cut out the last 4 numbers of each assignment, before the last hash, and match that up with the assignment ID in the metabase sheet. I think because it's a query when I just matched to column A in the metabase sheet, I got N/A, but when I used an array formula, I got the assignment IDs, and the repeated 9/10/2018 dates were returned in the index:match function. I moved the array formula function to row 1299 for better visibility, but there were no changes from when the array formula was on line 2.

```
=index('metabase data'!Q:Q, MATCH(left(Right(K2, 5), 4),'metabase data'!S:S),false)
```

I'm hoping for the Start Date column to return the start dates that are in the metabase sheet, corresponding to the assignment IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(K21:K, 5), 4)), 
 {VALUE('metabase data'!A:A), 'metabase data'!Q:Q}, 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Nailed it! I don't understand it, but it works haha